# Error showing in while using ternary operator l value required as left operand of assignment

Tags: c, if-statement, conditional-operator, operator-precedence

**Showing error l value required as left operand of assignment**

```
#include<stdio.h>
void main()
{
    int i,j,l,n,s;
    printf("Enter the number size you want to print :");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    for(i=-n;i<=n;i++)
    {
        (i<0)? l=-i:l=i;
        for(j=0;j<l+1;j++)
        { 
            printf("* ");
        } 
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

**i want to write this one in ternary operator**

```
if(i<0)
        {
            l=-i;
        }
        else
        {
            l=i;
        }
```

Comment: How about `l = (i < 0) ? -i : i`?

Comment: Or better yet, use [the standard `abs` funciton](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/abs)? Like `l = abs(i);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In C the conditional operator is defined the following way (6.5.15 Conditional operator)

```
conditional-expression:
    logical-OR-expression
    logical-OR-expression ? expression : conditional-expression
```

That is the last expression in the conditional operator  does not accept the assignment operator because the assignment operator has a lower precedence than the conditional operator. So your statement

```
(i<0)? l=-i:l=i;
```

is equivalent to

```
( (i<0)? l=-i:l ) = i;
```

Instead you need to write

```
(i<0)? l=-i: ( l=i );
```

Opposite to C in C++ the conditional operator is defined the following way (C++17 Standard, 8.16 Conditional operator)

```
conditional-expression:
    logical-or-expression
    logical-or-expression ? expression : assignment-expression
```

So if to compile your program as a C++ program then this statement

```
(i<0)? l=-i:l=i;
```

will be valid.

In any case you could rewrite the operator the following way

```
l = i < 0 ? -i : i;
```

and this statement will be valid in C and C++.

Answer (score 2):

```
(i<0)? l=-i:l=i;
```

change this line to

```
l=(i<0)?-i:i;
```

Comment: Also: `l += abs(i)`.